# Linq Query with double sub queries

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework

I am struggling converting the following SQL query I wrote into Linq. I think I'm on the right track, but I must be missing something.

The error I'm getting right now is:

> System.Linq.IQueryable does not contain a definition for .Contains

Which is confusing to me because it should right?

**SQL**

```
select Users.*
from Users
where UserID in (select distinct(UserID)
                        from UserPermission
                        where SupplierID in (select SupplierID
                                             from UserPermission
                                             where UserID = 6))
```

**LINQ**

```
var Users = (from u in _db.Users
             where (from up in _db.UserPermissions select up.UserID)
               .Distinct()
               .Contains((from up2 in _db.UserPermissions
                          where up2.UserID == 6
                          select up2.SupplierID))
             select u);
```

**EDIT:** I ended up going back to SqlCommand objects as this was something I had to get done today and couldn't waste too much time trying to figure out how to do it the right way with Linq and EF. I hate code hacks :(

Comment: I do. This query is just one inside of a big repository

Comment: Are UserID and SupplierID of the same type?

Comment: Yes they are. Both are `int` in the Database

Comment: `Contains` method expects just one element, you're passing another collection, which is why there is no overload that could be called.

Comment: Why do you want to translate exactly this SQL query? The same can be written  in the more efficient way. Also, you must provide the your entity model for better assistance.

Comment: I'd be all for a more efficient way. That SQL query was just the first thing that I wrote that did what I wanted to do, which was return a list of all users who have the same suppliers as the user id that I pass into it.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no need to do a `distinct` here (maybe I am wrong). But here is a simpler version (assuming you have all the navigational properties defined correctly)

```
var lstUsers = DBContext.Users.Where(
                    x => x.UserPermissions.Any(
                                    y => y.Suppliers.Any(z => z.UserID == 6)
                                            )
                                    ).ToList();
```

Above if you have `UserID` field in `Supplier` entity, if it is NOT you can again use the navigational property as,

```
var lstUsers = DBContext.Users.Where(
                    x => x.UserPermissions.Any(
                                    y => y.Suppliers.Any(z => z.User.UserID == 6)
                                            )
                                    ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

`Contains()` only expects a single element, so it won't work as you have it written.  Try this as an alternate:

```
var Users = _db.Users
            .Where(u => _db.UserPermissions
                .Select(x => UserID)
                .Distinct()
                .Where(x => _db.UserPermissions
                    .Where(y => y.UserID == 6)
                    .Select(y => y.SupplierID)
                    .Contains(x))
                );
```

Comment: Appreciate the attempt, but now it errors out on the `.Where` with `Cannot implicity convert System.Linq.IQueryable<int> to bool`

Comment: Once it gets this complex, I tend to stop using the easy LINQ syntax and go for the code. I'm going to writing this, as I believe the problem is with some missing parenthesis.

Comment: Could be, I'm probably just going to switch this one query back over to old school SqlCommand object query. Linq is awesome, but for the more complex queries I find it lacking at times.

Comment: Just posted the revised version.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try on my side but you can try using the let keyword:

```
var Users = (from u in _db.Users
             let distinctUsers = (from up in _db.UserPermissions select up).Distinct()
             let subQuery = (from up2 in _db.UserPermissions
                          where up2.UserID == 6
                          select up2)
             where 
             distinctUsers.SupplierID== subQuery.SupplierID && 
             u.UserID==distinctUsers.UserID
             select u);
```